# Proof by induction

Tags: induction

This is a topic I always struggle with. Could someone help me prove this:

Prove by induction: 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n 2k = n^2 + n,
$$
Thanks for any help

Comment: There is a base case ($n=1$) and an induction step (if it is true for $n$ then also for $n+1$). Show us your "struggling" on this. This by editing your question (not a comment).

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Answer (score 1):

Check for $n=1$. It is true.

Assuming it is true for $a$,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^a 2k &= a^2 + a\\
\sum_{k=1}^a 2k+2(a+1) &= a^2 + a+2(a+1)\\
\sum_{k=1}^{a+1} &= a^2 + a+2(a+1)\\
&=(a^2+2a+1)+a+1\\
&=(a+1)^2+(a+1)
\end{align}$$

It then follows that it is true for $a+1$. Then, because it is true for $1$, it is true for $1+1=2$, $2+1=3$, and so on. It is true for all positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Base case holds easily.For next Step Hint $$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2k = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2k 
 +2n$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider

**Step 1:** $n=1$ and try to show that your equation is true

**Step 2:** Let consider your equation is true for $n=m$ and try to show it is also true for $n= m+1$. Then you will be done.

**Note:** $\sum_{k=1}^n 2k = 2\times \frac{n^2 + n}2 = n^2 + n$. So without induction you can prove this easily.